# Devise Reconfirmable - alternative email is not picked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I am allowing users to change their email in Devise.

Since this commit : https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/commit/ce071502eeb5c5c5199436f6694bfb6103010c4a it is possible to send an alternative email than the usual "Welcome" Registration email.

Devise mailer now includes a specific method for this: https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/master/app/mailers/devise/mailer.rb

I have then created 2 different views in my **my_model/views/mailer** folder: email_changed.html.erb and email_changed.text.erb

Though this alternative email is never picked. The original Welcome email is sent instead...

Am I missing something ?

===

My Devise version is  4.7.3 (also I am coming from an old version)

and my devise initializer has `config.reconfirmable = true`

I have seen this hack but I guess it shouldn't need be used anymore : [How to send two different emails for devise confirmable and devise reconfirmable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15770070/how-to-send-two-different-emails-for-devise-confirmable-and-devise-reconfirmable)

Answer (score 1):

Is that `my_model/views/mailer` folder right? according to the code (*) it should be `views/my_model/mailer`.

- https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/45b831c4ea5a35914037bd27fe88b76d7b3683a4/lib/devise/mailers/helpers.rb#L66

I would suggest you to copy that helper file inside your project so you can put some byebug statement and properly debug it.

Comment: oops sure it was a typo. I generated Devise controllers and views for the model. So views/my_model/mailer is correct.
Good idea. I will copy this file and check what it gives.

Comment: Also I am wondering is email changed method is not only used when the initializer `send_email_change_notification` is set to true. In which case it would be only triggered when we want an email been sent to the original email of the user (and not the new email). When using Devise to reconfirm to the new email the usual registration method may be used .. I think I will use the hack instead of digging too far into Devise ..